# Read the text of some files and put in a listview (Visual Basic)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to read the contents of some files and put in a listview. In every file of this determinated folder there's a 6 digit-code. I need to put in a listview

[image: ListView]

I wrote this:

```
For Each file In code = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(directory)
    ListView1.Items.Add(file)
Next
```

sBut it says "access denied" to the following directory. Which is Strange because I used this directory in other parts of my program.

Comment: You cannot `ReadAllText()` of a Directory object. What is `directory`? A `DirectoryInfo`? Maybe you want something like `dim dir = new DirectoryInfo("Path") for each f As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles("*.txt") ListView1.Items.Add(File.ReadAllText(f.FullName)) next`.

Comment: Can you show an example of the lines in your text files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the files in the directory first.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    'The string must contain the complete path to the directory
    'including the directory name
    Dim pathToDirectory As String = "C:\Documents\MyDirectory"
    For Each f As String In Directory.GetFiles(pathToDirectory)
        ListView1.Items.Add(File.ReadAllText(f))
    Next
End Sub
```